# Can Docker labels be used while building a Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

If I define a label inside a Dockerfile

```
LABEL foo=bar
```

can I then use `foo` in the image build process?

Comment: In what way do you want to use `foo` in the build process? You may need to be more specific

Comment: @MattB.I would like to use that define label within a RUN order, let's san RUN echo $foo or something like that. I guess that what I'm looking for is using labels as environment variables.

Comment: Ok gotcha, I've put up an answer.

Answer (score 0):

What I think you're looking for is the `ENV` command, you can use it as you've mentioned:

```
ENV foo="bar"
RUN echo $foo
```

Here's the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#env), hope it helps!

Comment: I know the ENV command. What I'm looking for is to use the LABEL command as I would the ENV command, or to initialize ENV values from LABEL values.

Answer (score -1):

You can use label during docker build

```
docker build . --label "version=1.0"
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not exactly what I'm looking for. I already have the label in the Dockerfile; I would like to use it somewhere else in the Dockerfile as explained above.

Comment: @jjmerelo Any luck? I tried something like `RUN echo '$(description)'` for a `LABEL description="This is an example description"` but it seems that labels are not regarded as variables like `ARG` is.

Comment: @rbaleksandar no luck at all. Presumably, the right answer is "just use `ARG` instead of `LABEL`"

Comment: I actually created an `ARG` with the string and pass it to the `LABEL`. :) I still have the issue with `echo`ing the value but I'll get to it eventually. :D